# Which path to take to Moonrise Towers if I don't want to miss any content?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

After finishing the goblin camp story arc, the druid Halsin told me there are two different ways I can go to get to Moonrise Towers. Either the Mountain Road or the path through the Underdark.

Without revealing any spoilers - does it have any major consequences if I pick one way over the other? That is: will I be missing out some content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notably, during Early Access of the game, you couldn't take the Mountain Road, only the Underdark path. So the dialogue with Halsin (or Minthara) was written before you had an option available here.

**I would strongly recommend everyone to take *both* paths.** The whole Underdark area is pretty big and entirely optional, as is the Rosymorn Monastry/githyanki crèche area. Both ways contain lots of quests, encounters and unique artifacts. You'll definitely not want to miss out either one of these, although the game *will* let you do that.

For the most enjoyable first time play-through, I would recommend the following route so that you will not miss out on anything:

- Finish all of "Act 1", the entire druid grove/goblin camp map which might end with a final battle.
- Locate an entrance to the Underdark. There are several of them in fact, one far more obvious than the others if you follow the main quests.
- Finish all of the Underdark (kind of "Act 1.5"), including the Grymforge map. Do not take the elevator in Grymforge just yet.
- Go back to the "Act 1" map and now take the Mountain pass route. You will end up in the Rosymorn Monastry area.
- After that map, you can either progress to Act 2 by taking the land route from Rosymorn or by taking the Grymforge elevator - it doesn't matter which way.

If you played your cards right, you will by now have some pretty neat artefacts before going to Act 2, some which are good enough to suffice as equipment until the very end of the game:

> You could by now have crafted a Sussur bark weapon, several pieces of Adamantine equipment and found the Legendary Blood of Lathander mace. All of these are quite intricate to get your hands on.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a note to [@Amarth's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/404305):

You can get back to any waypoint from Act 1 until almost the end of Act 2: the point of no return is quite late and it is located in the depth of the Temple of Shar (**after** completing the trials). You will receive a prompt saying that "following this path will move the story forward".

This means that you can, for example, go via the Underdark to the Act 2 proper, complete most of the quests there (there might be some issues story-wise if you go to Moonrise towers before going to the Ancient Forge, but I'm not 100% sure) and then teleport back to the Goblin Village from Act 1 and head via the Mountain Passage to the Githyanki creche, or other way around.

Comment: I think the story might be even more mixed up if you don't do the Underdark first... but well, it's already a mess either way. I'm on my 2nd playthrough I'm scavenging through the shadow curse area and then Shadowheart makes comments like "there must have been a temple to Shar here"... err? No s*** girl - we just spent quite some time hiking through one, remember? In fact that's why you are wearing those Dark Justiciar items. But then she has this memory problem so she might be excused :)

Comment: Also I'd say it's strongly recommended to side either with Halsin or Minthara in Act 1 or you will be missing out so much content. You can just ignore them and just march on, but that's going to be one big 'meh'. NPCs from Act 1 transfer to Act 2 (and 3) so if you didn't finish Act 1 proper then that won't happen.

Comment: If you don't side with either Halsin or Minthara in Act 1, you are still able to recruit Minthara in Act 2.